# gradle build failed (exporting)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle, build

when I try to get Android export with Unity, it gives me "Gradle build failed" error. With the same version of Unity that I have, it does not give this error for my other games and it only gives this error in this game. What should I do?

Thanks [Error details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WibxR.png)

I changed my gradle to others version but it wasn't useful.

Comment: Did you read the part of the error message where it says your path contains non-ascii characters that will most likely cause the build to fail?

Comment: @RetiredNinja  Excuse me. What is your suggestion?

Comment: Move your project somewhere that doesn't have any special characters or spaces in the pathname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check these options:

1. check that path of the project is not too long (address characters not more than 256)
2. click "Force Resolve" from this path ==> Assets/External Dependency Manager/Android Resolver/Force Resolve
3. Maybe you need good vpn for gradle.